# Ubuntu Server does not appear on network by NetBIOS name until 2nd reboot?

Tags: server, 10.04, samba, lts

Currently having a strange issue whereby my Ubuntu LTS 10.04 Server does not appear on the network on first boot after being shut down.  I am able to connect to the server using the assigned IP, but not via the NetBIOS name.

I am using `sudo shutdown -h now` to perform a safe shutdown and power off the system.

Currently, I have tried to troubleshoot the problem by restarting the samba service and restarting networking but neither of these attempts allow the server to be seen on the network.

The only thing that seems to fix the problem is if I restart the server after it boots successfully for the first time.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm at a total loss here.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think something you installed might be causing this. What programs do you have installed that are not stock with ubuntu server? You might also want to try "shutdown -s now" to shutdown, which might fix it. Safe restart does not really make a difference when dealing with servers

c:

Regards, 
Stefan.

Comment: It seems that the issue is related to the WINS implementation.  I am able to connect to the server using the assigned IP, but not the WINS hostname.  Any ideas here?  I imagine this would be Samba related?